How to split and sample "Panel Data" when training a Logistic Regression to predict future outcomes
Introduction
I have panel data where customer behavior is observed over time. For each customer at a given reference date, I have a lookback window of 12 months for generating features, and a look forward window of 12 months for identifying an outcome e.g. unsubscribing, defaulting or the likes.

Each customer exists on a monthly basis in my data set, in the following way:

Now I would like to train a logistic regression to predict a binary outcome, and this is where I have a bunch of questions. I have mostly only been able to find blogs and books about the validation of time-series, but not about panel data. But here are my thoughts that I would like to have input on.
What is Best Practice for splitting?
I need to split my dataset into train/valid/test, where train/valid will be used for training a logistic regression and an adversarial model (validation data is used for hyper-parameter tuning and early stopping), and the test data will be used for the final evaluation.
As the model(s) will have to perform over time and on new customers, I would like to do two types of "out-of-sample" validations: 1) A temporal validation (out-of-time) to make sure it works on future unseen data, 2) An "external validation", such that the same customers do not exist in the training data, the validation data and the test data.

What is "best practice" for splitting Panel Data?
Most blog post mention doing a "out-of-time" validation, but none really mention doing validations on samples that do not exist in the training data. Is this last part not necessary?
How do you handle "serial correlations"?
In logistic regression, the assumption of independence among observations is often important. Having the same customer appear multiple times in the training data (with likely correlated variables and outcomes) violates this assumption, as their monthly observations are not truly independent. This could lead to underestimated standard errors and overconfident predictions because the model would not account for the within-subject correlation.
What is "best practice" for handling these "serial correlations"?
Some ideas I have for handling this:

Only keep a single customer a single time in the data

A potential issue is that I might loose too much data on important segments, and on the binary outcome


Use Clustered Standard Errors

Clustering is done of non-independent observations (customers), and a corrected standard error is calculated that accounts for the within-customer correlations.


Use Generalized Estimating Equations (GEE)

I am not quite familiar with these, but they should also be able to adjust model metrics based on correlation structures in the data



How would you validate the temporal aspect of the model?
I would like the model to be performant over time, as much as possible, but it has a trade-off in terms of how much time to set aside for the tests. It is pretty well-proven that the "recent past" predicts the future better than the "distant past". But I was considering something like this, where I evaluate the model separately on a monthly basis for my evaluation period of 2 years with and without calibration (adjusting predicted rates to observed rates the past year).
The reason for this whole "calibration" step is that we expect the model's ranking performance to be consistent over time, while the overall outcome rate is expected to change over time.
What is the "best practice" for getting the most "trust worthy" evaluation metric that work over time?

Do you have other cool tips and tricks?
There is probably a lot of things I am missing here, so please feel free to come with other recommendations and best practices.

My personal take is that only real hold out of customers provides you with an unbiased estimate for the performance on new customers. On the other hand: If your universe is fixed (no new customers) and your customer behavior always stays the same you could perform performance estimation on hold out times (not complete holdout customers)... In my opinion you will be in case 1 in the real world. Also look into the concept of pseudo replication/ repeated measures

How about if one makes the test data a proportion of old customers and new customers? I suspect that around 85-90 % of our customers will be the same over a period of 10 years.

Best Practice for Splitting Panel Data
For splitting panel data, the following approaches are often considered best practices:

Temporal Validation (Out-of-Time)
This involves setting aside data from the most recent time period as a validation and/or test set. For example, if you have data from 2016 to 2020, you might use data up to 2019 for training and 2020 data for testing. This approach simulates how the model will perform on future, unseen data.
Cross-sectional Validation (External Validation)
This approach involves ensuring that the same customers are not present in both the training and validation/test sets. This can be implemented by splitting customers into different groups, where one group is entirely held out for validation/testing.
A combination (Out-of-Time and External Validation)
The most robust approach is to use a combination of the two approaches above, where the model is validated on unseen customers that are also out-of-time. For some use-cases this can be too conservative though, e.g. if you have 100 % customer retention in the future.

Handling Serial Correlations
Serial correlation is a common issue in panel data, and there is not one right way to handle this. Each have their strengths and pitfalls.

Keep a Single Observation Per Customer
This is the simplest approach but may lead to a significant loss of data and potential under-representation of customer behavior over time as e.g. old customers and new customers will be equally represented.
Clustered Standard Errors
This is a common technique in econometrics where the standard errors are adjusted to account for non-independence within clusters of data (e.g., customers). This, however, does not solve potential issues with incorrect estimations of coefficients.
Generalized Estimating Equations (GEE)
GEE can account for the correlation structure within the data and provide robust estimates. It is more flexible than traditional logistic regression and can specify different types of correlation structures.
Random Effects or Mixed Models
These models allow for individual-level random effects that can absorb some of the serial correlation by modeling the within-subject variability. The issue with this approach is that if you add a ID variable, then you cannot really use the model for prediction. Adding a time-variable can, however, relieve some of the issue.

Validating the Temporal Aspect of the Model
Again, there is not one right answer for how to do this, and each approach has its own trade-offs.

Sliding Window Validation:
Train on a rolling window of time and predict the next period. For example, train on months 1-12, predict month 13, then train on months 2-13 and predict month 14, and so on. This provides some of the most reliable estimates of real world performance.


Expanding Window Validation:
Similar to rolling window validation but the training set expands over time. Start with a base period and gradually add more data for training, predicting the next period each time. While you will use the data more efficiently, there different models will be less comparable.


Calibration
If you expect the outcome rates to change over time, recalibrating the model's intercept (while keeping the coefficients fixed) can help adjust for shifts in the base rate.


Trustworthy Evaluation Metric Over Time
Evaluating over a longer unseen period is the best measure of how the model will perform in the future, but again it is a trade-off between validation and then having sufficient data to train the model. You cannot have both in many cases. Having data from a longer period will result in a more robust model, as the effects of temporal events will be smoothed out, but then you will lack data to do a proper validation.

"There seems to be no consensus on what best practice is for splitting/sampling panel data". This is due to the fact that you may group these data in very different ways (e.g. by customer, by day, ....). The point is, that e.g. sometimes it may not even be best to treat your data as panel data. Say you have three companies as customer, but essentially it was just one company which changed its name two times (which means correlated data in your panel like data), then it is more a forecasting problem than a panel data problem. It's all about sensible groupings for your problem and model performance (you can build both types of models). I feel this is related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-automl-forecasting-methods?view=azureml-api-2 especially the section "Model grouping"
If the grouping for your problem is not properly reflected in your test/train splits you will run into the problem of pseudo replication https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoreplication

So if my data is highly correlated it will lead to pseudo-replication. Was also the same conclusion I came to. But using a logistic regression with clustered evaluation metrics, I suspect it won't matter much, as in out panel data 95+ % of customers are equally represented via repeat monthly measures.
